# DumpSave and precision of interpolation data

Tags: interpolation, arbitrary-precision, dumpsave

Consider the following

```
prec = 32;
x = N[Range[0, 1, 1/10], prec];
f = Interpolation[Transpose@{x, x}];
```

Then

```
Precision /@ {f["Coordinates"], f["ValuesOnGrid"]}
```

gives

```
{32., 32.}
```

as expected. Now if I export `f` using `DumpSave[]` and read it back

```
DumpSave["~/tmp/f.mx", f];Clear[f];Get["~/tmp/f.mx"];
```

then surprisingly

```
Precision /@ {f["Coordinates"], f["ValuesOnGrid"]}
```

returns

```
{32., MachinePrecision}
```

Is it a bug on "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" and "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)", and how to fix this?

Comment: You can save only the coordinates and re-run the `Interpolation` again after getting data back. It does not take too much time..